Flutter emoji value is reversed in controller when using rtl text direction
I have a textfield in flutter as follows:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      maxLines: null,
      onChanged: (value) {
        print(value);
      },
      autofocus: false,
      controller: smcontroller,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xffffffff),
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: AppLocalizations.translate('Type a message'),
        hintTextDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      ),
    );
  }


When I type hello in the textfield, the textfield correctly shows "hello". But the value on onChanged callback shows "hello" and the controller also has same value. I want the controller to also have "hello".

The directionality of the output from the print function depends on how you set up the terminal. If you have correctly set up the Flutter widgets to use RTL directionality, whether through the Directionality widget or the textDirection property of TextField, you don't need to worry about the reversed output from the terminal.

I need to save and use the value. It's not about printing in the terminal. When I save the value in database, it is not the same value as I see in the textfield. Somehow, it gets changed when I use emoji.

Again, how do you verify the content of the DB? If you use some viewer that uses LTR, of course you'll see the same issue. The important thing is that when you consume the data and display it in your widget, it shows the correct directionality.

In other words, LTR vs RTL is about how the data is presented to the user. It doesn't matter how it's stored, as long as the same input results in the same output when used in the same "viewer" (in this case, the Flutter widget).

I use the db value to be displayed in the text widget with RTL direction. The text with emoji shows incorrectly while others work well.

That's the problem with your displaying widget. You should also make it use RTL. There's a Directionality widget which you can wrap all widgets that need to display its content in RTL with it.

In short, the problem arises when the input widget is using RTL, but the displaying widget is still using LTR. I think you confuse it by thinking that the problem is with how the text is stored.
